# Specify location for ipa file in Xcode 7 Ad-Hoc release

Tags: ios9, ipa, xcode7

UPDATE: This issue is still present in Xcode 7.1 beta 2. Looks like this will be here a while.

I just updated to Xcode 7 GM and am in the process of generating ad-hoc archives for various builds. However, it does not appear that you can specify the directory path where you want to save the resulting .ipa file. It is going straight to the desktop in a pre-named folder that includes a timestamp.

Steps to (hopefully) reproduce

1. From the main menu, select Product --> Archive
2. In the resulting window, select 'Export...'
3. Choose 'Save for Ad Hoc Deployment' and select 'Next'
     (other methods seems to exhibit the same behavior)
4. Choose the provisioning profile and select 'Choose'
5. In the 'Device Support' window, select 'Export one app for all compatible devices'
6. In the 'Summary' window, select 'Next'

Rather than enabling the 'Export' button (which previously allowed the user to select the destination), it now directly saves the .ipa in a folder on the desktop.

It is more of an annoyance that a required feature, but it is a pain that it appears you cannot specify the destination folder for the archive.

Anyone else have this issue and/or know how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: same here, I couldn't find a way to make Xcode ask for the destination path.

Comment: same. I looked at the doco and the doco still says it should ask for a location https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: if it were for Apple, computers should only have one folder: the Desktop

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the latest version of Xcode (7.3) allows you to select the destination and folder name that contains the IPA file when generating ad-hoc releases.

Answer (score 3):

Xcode generate .ipa file automatically on your desktop. It should be in the directory named from your app+date. If you cannot find it then try: CMD+space and type [name of archive].ipa and you should find it :)
Hope it helps.

Comment: can we change that location in our custom folder?

Comment: How did this get upvoted? Doesn't answer the question at all. In fact, OP states what you said in their question already.

Comment: I guess because some people are ok with the ipa's being sent to the desktop which is why they upvoted...but most definitely does not answer the OP's specific question.