# generating .ipa file from xCode

Tags: xcode, xcode7

It's the first time I'm generating an application .According to this question :
[Specify location for ipa file in Xcode 7 Ad-Hoc release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573321/specify-location-for-ipa-file-in-xcode-7-ad-hoc-release)  , the solution saying that from product menu choose archive . But I don't have archive in product menu .

I'm using xcode 7 .

What's wrong ?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of your "Product" Menu ?

Comment: For Archive make sure you have the device as an actual device or Generic IOS Device and not one of the Simulators otherwise it is greyed out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 4 - "Archive" is greyed out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266350/xcode-4-archive-is-greyed-out)

Answer (score 3):

Select Generic iOS device in device menu.

[image]

OR

Select an actual device -->

[image]

It basically cannot create an archive for a simulator.